# Javascript Function Find

Tags: javascript, jquery, mocha.js

I have been giving some JavaScript to look at and I'm finding it hard to solve this.

I need to write a function to findByName the correct name with the name Tom Jones passed in.

So far I have this..

```
  LocatorService.prototype.findByDirector = function() {

  };


     describe('Describe text', function () {
        it('Sub Text', function() {
          var locatorService = new Search.LocatorService(data);
          var expectedResult = [data[0]];
          expect(locatorService.findByName('Tom Jones')).to.eql(expectedResult);
        });
      });



      var data = [
        {
          title: 'Movie 1',
          startFate: new Date('2015-01-01'),
          cast: [],
          crew: [
            { credit: 'Director', name: 'Tom Jones' },
            { credit: 'Producer', name: 'Bill Baily' }
          ]
        },
```

Any ideas, really new to object orientated java script.

Comment: how this is related to jquery?

Comment: Loop through data [for loop], each index of data, reference crew, loop through crew, compare the credit for Director, get the name.

Comment: Could you show a example how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the thing that you want?
[underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#where) is good!